# Cypress: How do I pass a selected property from API response to another API request?

Tags: cypress

I would like to use Cypress for API testing. My goal is to extract a part of the API response and pass it to another API request. Here's a sample code:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('createCustomer', () => {
    return cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'api/v1/Customers',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: {
            // sample content
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {        
            expect(response).property('status').to.equal(201)
            expect(response.body).property('id').to.not.be.oneOf([null, ""])
            const jsonData = response.body;
            const memberId = jsonData.id
            resolve(memberId)
            return memberId
        })
    })
})
```

With this code, I am getting [object%20Object] as the result. [image]

Hoping for some feedback.

Comment: Can you also mention how you are using the value from API 1 to API 2, as in the example I can see just one request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are adding the id generated by the `POST` to a subsequent `GET` request?

Try returning the id without using a Promise, I don't think you need one at that point since the response has already arrived.

```js
}).then((response) => {
  expect(response).property('status').to.equal(201)
  expect(response.body).property('id').to.not.be.oneOf([null, ""])
  const jsonData = response.body;
  const memberId = jsonData.id;
  return memberId;
})
```

Url for GET

```
cy.createCustomer().then(id => {
  const url = `api/v1/Customers${id}`;
  ...
```

or

```
cy.createCustomer().then($id => {
  const id = $id[0];       // Not quite sure of the format, you may need to "unwrap" it
  const url = `api/v1/Customers${id}`;
  ...
```

Comment: It totally worked! Thanks a lot Marion! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass response from API Request 1 to API Request 2, you can do something like this:

```
describe('Example to demonstrate API Chaining in Cypress', function () {

    it('Chain two API requests and validate the response', () => {
        //Part 1
        cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=sn',
        }).then((response) => {
            const location = response.body[0].title
            return location
        })
            //Part 2
            .then((location) => {
                cy.request({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=' + location
                }).then((response) => {
                    expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
                    expect(response.body[0]).to.have.property('title', location)
                })
            })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be failing during the initial request, not during the subsequent actions. I am far from a Javascript expert, but you seem to have some unnecessary complexity in there. Try simplifying your command like this and see if you can at least get a successful request to go through:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('createCustomer', () => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'api/v1/Customers',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: {
            // sample content
        }
    })
})
```

And if that works, keep going:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('createCustomer', () => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'api/v1/Customers',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: {
            // sample content
        }
    }).then((response) => {      
        expect(response).property('status').to.equal(201)
        expect(response.body).property('id').to.not.be.oneOf([null, ""])
        const jsonData = response.body;
        const memberId = jsonData.id
        return memberId
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi, the original request works. I purposedly did not disclose the entire request for confidentiality reasons, but thanks for checking thou.